# Sending jwt through header response with resolver mutation GraphQL and Appollo server

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, jwt, apollo-server

Today I'v been trying to send a jwt token back to the client via a header.

Sadly I cant get it to work, my current code looks like this.

the resolver/mutation

```js
    // log user in
    Login: async(parent, args, context, info) =>{
      const LoginUser = await user.findOne({username: args.username})
      if (LoginUser.password == args.password){
        //loginsucces
        const token = jwt.sign({id: user.id}, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
        
        context.res.header  = ("auth", token)

        LoginUser.token =  token;
        
        return LoginUser;
      }else{
        return LoginUser;
      }           
    }
```

app.js

```js
const server = new ApolloServer({ 
  typeDefs, 
  resolvers,
  context: ({ res }) => ({
    res
  })
});
```

For some reason the code doesnt recognise .header so it wont send the token. Currently i send it via the token field form the user. But that takes up space in my mongodb, and destroys the whole purpose of jwt.

Am I just forgetting a function or not getting it?

Comment: ... and the tutorial you're following is ???

Comment: Im not following a tutorial, why would you assume that? I watched some videos of ben awad, but he codes in typescript, this is javascript. So not everything matches. If i could refer a video it would be this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUZB8tpyDbQ

Comment: https://github.com/benawad/jwt-auth/blob/1_jwt/server/src/resolvers.ts

Comment: as i said earlier, he uses typescript, im using javascript. So the code doesnt correspond 1:1. He just uses {res} in his mutation. This is something im not able to do with just javascript. It wont recognize the response. Many people suggest defining the response in the context, which i did as shown above, but i still dont get it to work.

Comment: rename ts to js and remove types, it should work ... *' code doesnt recognise `.header` '* - no need to use `.header` ... use `res.cookie` as in source?

Comment: res.cookie is not recognized aswell. I dont use his code btw, i wrote my own code, just watched his vid for info and explainations.

Comment: `res.cookie()` is an `express` function - is it properly confifgured? - follow [some working] example more strictly?

Comment: hm, i dont think i have it imported within the resolver file tho, ben doesnt have it aswell in his resolver.ts github.com/benawad/jwt-auth/blob/1_jwt/server/src/resolvers.ts

Comment: eh, it's a server (not resolver) part ... https://github.com/benawad/jwt-auth/blob/1_jwt/server/src/index.ts

Comment: I just talked with my supervisor, he suggested me to just switch to ts because its more efficient anyway. Thanks for the help tho!

Comment: more safe - sure, more efficient - not, ts is compiled to js and run with almost the same code, in the same env ... nothing better than compiling type checking